# i am trying to submit from with ajax but only imagename name not post on the next page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $("#submit").click(function()
                                    {

                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var pass = $("#pass").val();
                    var image = $("#imagefile").val();
                    var comm = $("#comment").val();



                var data = 'name=' +name+ '&pass=' +pass+ '&imagefile=' +image+ '&comment='+comm;   

                    if(name=="" || pass=="")
                    {
                    $("#error").show();
                    return false;
                    }



        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "submit.php",
           data: data, 
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

I


            });

});
```

i am trying to submit from with ajax but only imagename name not post on the next page.

Comment: do you want to upload an image with form submission?

Comment: i just want to get imagename or file name on the next page(submit.php)

Comment: i got username,password ,comment but not getting imagename or file name. pls help

Comment: I think you are searching this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: @munjal yaa i m searching for something like this. but still my problem is not solved

Comment: Does the file input have id="imagefile"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submit.php",
   data: {name: name, pass : pass, imagefile: image, comment : comm}, 
   success: function(data)
   {
       // success code 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have attribute ***enctype="multipart/form-data"*** included in your form tag.